# Binance PHP API

Tags: php, binance, binance-chain

I try to get this done from github. https://github.com/binance-exchange/php-binance-api

I installed Xampp (latest version: 7.2.3) on a win 10 machine. Xampp is running. (at least not mysql, because it has an error while starting, but mysql is not needed). I downloaded the files from github and puttet them into my htdocs in a new folder called "binance". I downloaded the install-file for composer from here: https://getcomposer.org/doc/00-intro.md#installation-windows Installed it and choosed the php.exe out of my xampp folder inside the installation-process.

Composer starts out of the console, and it works. I put this command into the cmd:

> php composer.phar require "jaggedsoft/php-binance-api @dev"

It installs some folders and files, into my project-directory. it's right.

Inside of the files downloaded from github, there is a file called:
**php-binance-api-test.php**

Inside this file, there are different lines like:

```
require 'vendor/autoload.php';
file_put_contents( getenv("HOME") . "/.config/jaggedsoft/php-binance-api.json"
```

But he is not able to find ".config/jaggedsoft/" because there is no folder named .config. There is also no file named php-binance-api.json only one called php-binance-api.php

I would be really thankful, if someone may try to get this run an tell me, what I have done wrong.

Answer (score 1):

I have had the same problem on my Ubuntu server and I could solve it by setting HOME directory at the top of my scripts as:

```
putenv("HOME=/var/www/html/");
```

My config is at a directory of

`/var/www/html/.config/jaggedsoft`

File name is `php-binance-api.json` and file content is:

```
{
"api-key": "ApiKeyHere",
"api-secret": "ApiSecretHere" 
}
```